# Custom serializer/converter for my json request to ASPNetCore 2 Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, vuejs2, entity-framework-core

**Before the storm (hahaha):**

Let's agree in something, DataSet has a magic (at least for me) due to cached-changes philosophy. It's so amazing for optimistic concurrency since I have the old(`DataRowVersiom.Original`) and new(`DataRowVersiom.Current`) valuesand . I've seen the way it works with WebServices (an old architecure), It holds changes for each row in XML format, the exchange data-structure for old and some actual apps. And there it comes my questions:

1. Is it possible to do the same with JSON, Entity Framework Core and Web API?
2. In case of not, should I implement a JsonConverter, some kind of Json Parser Behavior for Web API or Media Formatter? (this is the part when I'm a little bit lost)

**What's my purpose:**

I have this object coming from client

```
[{ //to modify
    id:1,
    name: "Pedro",
    "original:name": "Peter"
},{//to delete
    "original:id": "2" 
    "original:name": "Amy" 
},{//to add
    "name": "Bob" 
}]
```

My parser whould do something like by each item:

2. If all values are original, deletes the item.
3. If both of them are present, modifies the entity matched by "original:" prefixed properties.
4. If there's not "original:", adds the entity.

Finally: Is it valid to do this kind of job?

Comment: So - to be clear - you're not using a DataSet, correct? And you want to know if there's a way to cache values in a similar fashion that a DataSet does in 3 different layers : JSON (this confuses me), Entity Framework, and Web API?

Comment: @MarkC. No, I'm not using a DataSet. What I mean is to do the cache job in client (browser at first shot). and then send it to server. Later (key of the question), request-processor in ASP (parser mechanism) read the JSON in the format I think is appropiated to make the entitties job. Simply: client (Javascript) serializes the cached-changes, then request's object-parser, deserializes them as I remarked in the question.